# Templates with classes in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I define on main 2 variables m,n from new class S.
Then,  I want to swap them with the template function swap..
The question is: what are the methods that S use to run this code and how it look like? :

```
template <class T>
    void swap(T &a ,T &b)
    {
        T tmp= a; 
        a=b;
        b=tmp; 
    }

template <class T>
class S{ 
public:
    S:();  
    S:(const S& data);
    ~S();
    S &operator=(const S&g); 

};

int main(){
    S m,n; 
    swap(m,n);
    cout<< "m is "<<m<< "n is "<<n<<endl; 
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking about? I will call the copy ctor once and copy assignment op twice, if that's what you're after.

Comment: Well, the type must have a copy c'tor and assignment operator...

Comment: Yes, that's my intention. I know I need a default constractor and destractor, and I know I need a copy constructor and assignment operator, but how the class should look like.                        My visual means that an error:                                                                                                  template <class T>
class Myclass{                     
public:
 Myclass:();  
    Myclass:(const Myclass& data);
 ~Myclass();
 Myclass&operator=(const Myclass&g); 
 
};

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do here...how do you use the template?

Comment: I try to define the class S with it..

Comment: If you're asking what a copy-constructor, assignment-operator, etc.. "look like" there are plenty of examples in almost any C++ text. You know your class, you know what is in it, you know what needs to be copied, calculated, etc. Ultimately only you can craft the correct code to ensure it is right.

Comment: Yes but I can not compile it. Something is not right even though I do everything right.

Comment: Those two statements are by definition a contradiction. And without your code, we cannot tell you what you did *wrong*. Post it.

Comment: You might want to pick up a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: visual say :   argument list for class template "S" is missing

Comment: Without code, it didn't happen. *Post it*.

Comment: How I add code to comment?

Comment: You don't. Add it to the *question*.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Now where does `S` come into this? There is no `S` type that I can see. And there is no code for any of those members, those are all decls without any implementations. Edit: You're (a) not providing the required template parameter for your `S` class, and (b) have no code (at least none posted) for any of the S members. I concur with Angew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <class T>
class S
...
```

This code means that `S` is a class template. That is, S is not a class but a template.

```
S m,n;
```

This declares two variables of class `S`. Here is your problem: the syntax requires a class, and you gave it a template.

Solution: "instantiate" your template. To do it, append the template parameter to the name of the template:

```
S<int> m,n;
```

Another solution: get rid of the template:

```
// Removed the line "template <class T>" here
class S {
    ...
}
...
S m,n;
```

If you don't know which solution to use, use the second one, because it simplifies your code.

Comment: thank you! the main is given to me as it is..I just need to write the class S...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement your own class for your template function example, because you very certainly just want to swap numbers. 
However if you decide to make your own (whatever) template class, then you may have to overload the assignment operator and maybe define a proper constructor to use your swap function properly. For the standard output in your example you also have to overload this operator http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/. 
Unfortunately the other features you have to implement (and how) depend on what your (whatever) class should do.. Your question is not very certain in that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/). Note that, `A&` and `const A&` are two different types. Therefore, your `swap` function would only use the copy constructor ( assignment operator) of the parameter type `A&`, not `const A&`. Play with the following code.

```
template <class T>
void myswap(T &a, T &b) {
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

template <class T>
class A {
public:
    T t;
    A( T t_ ) : t(t_){}
    A( A& a){
        cout<<"In A's copy ctor A&a"<<endl;
        t = a.t;
    }    
    A& operator = (A& a){
        cout<<"In A's assignment operator A&a"<<endl;
        t = a.t;
    }
};

int main() {
    A<int> a1(3);
    A<int> a2(4);
    myswap(a1, a2);
    cout<<a1.t << "  " << a2.t <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
In A's copy ctor A&a
In A's assignment operator A&a
In A's assignment operator A&a
4  3
```